# c++ m bits permutations of a number

Tags: c++, statistics, combinatorics, permutation

I am searching for a function that get as an input a number *x* (assuming 15), number of bits *d* (4) and number of permutations *m* (2). The output of the function will be all the numbers that are *m* bit's permutations from the given number *x* at a *d* length bits.

For the given numbers, (*x* = 15, *d* = 4 and *m* = 2) we get `6=\binom{4}{2}`different number's combination.

I would like to know if such kind of function already exist in C++ STD or boost or etc. that returns me those numbers...

P.S.
if you know a function that returns all permutations' numbers till *m*.

regards

Comment: No such function in standard C++. Besides, I smell homework...

Comment: So, is *d* ever something other than `ceil(log2(x))`?

Comment: Not even in Boost, that i came across. You have to write your own custom function for it.

Comment: @DevSolar, no it is not HW. I need such kind of function to my program i use at my master thesis.
@Mike D. no. In this example i chose x=15, but i could have chosen x = 0 and d = 4...

Comment: @Eagle would this link help? http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation

Comment: @Gregory Pakosz, not exactly, since i not intresting shifting the 1 bits in the number, either changing exactly 2 bits each time, till i all possible combination are checked.

Comment: I need better examples.  I don't understand what you mean by 'm bit permutations'. f(x=4, d=2, m=2) => ?

Comment: @Caspin, the combination f(x=4, d=2, m=2) is not possible, since 4 is a 3 bits number and d<3 in your example. Lets take f(x=4, d=3, m=2), then we expect 3 numbers in our output: 2 (010) , 1 (001) , 7 (111). As you can see all those numbers contains exactly 2 bits which are different then the original number x=4 (100)

Answer (score 2):

i looked again at the comment from @Gregory Pakosz and i found out it was not so bad direction to start with. I tried to implement the suggested code from [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation) in my program and after some bugs in my code it worked.

Thanks